# Intercept minimize event on windows mobile (compact framework)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, window

I want to intercept minimize/maximize events for a windows mobile 6.1 application in c#. Is there a simple way to achieve this. (A piece of code as an example would be great).
I need to know when the user plays with my application or the application runs in background.

Comment: By intercept do you mean become aware of it happening, or try to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Without any testing I'd say: take a look at the Form.Activated and Form.Deactivated events:

From the C# Documentation:

- Form.Deactivate Event : Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.
- Form.Activate Event: Occurs when the form is activated in code or by the user.

Comment: In multiform app one form is deactivated when the other app form is displayed - need to trace all that stuff is doable but not fun.